# Why does -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue' work on script A but not B

Tags: performance, powershell, scheduled-tasks

Update2:

I changed script B to the following and the terminal shows two error output logs. Why would it choose both else statements at once?

```
##############################
######## CREATE TASKS ########
##############################
#
## ERROR STDOUT PREFERENCE ###
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
#
###### TIME-SPAN VALUE #######
$TimeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 3
#
##### WHEN TO RUN TASK #######
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
#
###### TASK OWNER INFO #######
$Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "$Env:USERDOMAIN\$Env:USERNAME" -LogonType Interactive -RunLevel Highest
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -StartWhenAvailable -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -Priority 0 -RestartCount 3 -RestartInterval $TimeSpan -ExecutionTimeLimit '00:00:00'
#
###### TASKS FOLDER NAME #####
$Folder = 'Start-Scripts'
#
######### TASKNAMES ##########
$TaskName1 = 'start_ahk_multiple_hotkeys'
$TaskName2 = 'start_ryzen_master'
$TaskName3 = 'start_corsair_link'
#
###### FOLDER + TASKNAME #####
$FullTask1 = "$Folder\$TaskName1"
$FullTask2 = "$Folder\$TaskName2"
$FullTask3 = "$Folder\$TaskName3"
#
############ AHK #############
$Action1 = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$Env:ProgramFiles\AHK\AutoHotkey.exe" -Argument "$Env:OneDrive\Documents\01_Scripts\02_AHK\Multiple_Hotkeys\Hotkeys_1.ahk"
#
########### RYZEN ############
$Action2 = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$Env:ProgramFiles\AMD\RyzenMaster\bin\AMD Ryzen Master.exe"
#
######## CorsairLink #########
$Action3 = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$Env:ProgramFiles(x86)\CorsairLink4\CorsairLink4.exe"
#
#########  IF EXISTS #########
if((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$FullTask1" -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue')){
   Write-Host "$FullTask1 - Already Exists" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
}
else{
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$FullTask1" -InputObject (
  New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action1 -Principal $Principal -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings
  )
  Write-Host "A task was created - $FullTask1"-ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
}

########  IF EXISTS 2 ########
if((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$FullTask2" -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue')){
  Write-Host "$FullTask2 - Already Exists" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
}
else{
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$FullTask2" -InputObject (
  New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action2 -Principal $Principal -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings
  )
Write-Host "A task was created - $FullTask2"-ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
}

########  IF EXISTS 3 ########
if((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$FullTask3" -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue')){
   Write-Host "$FullTask3 - Already Exists" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
}
else{
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$FullTask3" -InputObject (
  New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action3 -Principal $Principal -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings
  )
  Write-Host "A task was created - $FullTask3" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
}

###### EXIT PARAMETERS #######
Read-Host -Prompt 'Press Enter to exit'
```

Error output log in termal shows this when script is run.

```
Register-ScheduledTask : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\Users\jholl\OneDrive\Documents\01_Scripts\04_Task_Scheduler\Start_Programs\Scripts\1-Create_ALL_v3.ps1:45 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$FullTask1" -InputObj ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x800700b7,Register-ScheduledTask

A task was created - Start-Scripts\start_ahk_multiple_hotkeys
Register-ScheduledTask : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\Users\jholl\OneDrive\Documents\01_Scripts\04_Task_Scheduler\Start_Programs\Scripts\1-Create_ALL_v3.ps1:56 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$FullTask2" -InputObj ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x800700b7,Register-ScheduledTask

A task was created - Start-Scripts\start_ryzen_master
Register-ScheduledTask : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\Users\jholl\OneDrive\Documents\01_Scripts\04_Task_Scheduler\Start_Programs\Scripts\1-Create_ALL_v3.ps1:67 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$FullTask3" -InputObj ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x800700b7,Register-ScheduledTask

A task was created - Start-Scripts\start_corsair_link
Press Enter to exit:
```

Original Post:

I have two scripts which the same goal in the end achieve of creating multiple new scheduled tasks to run at user logon.

Script A does not utilize custom and global variables the way script B does and the line on script A below works but the same line on script B does not and produces STDOUT error logging. The error logs are annoying and confusing and unneeded in a working script that has already been perfected (or as close as your able).

```
if((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'start_ahk_multiple_hotkeys' -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue')){
```

Script A:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
########################################
### Create AHK Multiple Hotkeys Task ###
########################################
# Set folder\taskname or just taskname by itself
$TaskName1 = 'Start-Scripts\start_ahk_multiple_hotkeys'
# File paths
$Action1 = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
-Execute 'C:\Program Files\AHK\AutoHotkey.exe' `
-Argument 'C:\Users\jholl\OneDrive\Documents\01_Scripts\02_AHK\Multiple_Hotkeys\Hotkeys_1.ahk'
# User info
$Principal1 = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal `
-UserId 'JDESKTOP\jholl' `
-LogonType Interactive `
-RunLevel Highest
# When to run task
$Trigger1 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger `
-AtLogOn
# Task settings
$TimeSpan1 = New-TimeSpan `
-Minutes 3
$Settings1 = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet `
 -StartWhenAvailable `
 -AllowStartIfOnBatteries `
 -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries `
 -Priority 0 `
 -RestartCount 3 `
 -RestartInterval $TimeSpan1 `
 -ExecutionTimeLimit '00:00:00'

# If task already exists function

if((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'start_ahk_multiple_hotkeys' -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue')){
   Write-Host "$TaskName1" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
   Write-Host " - Already Exists" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
}
else{
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$TaskName1" -InputObject (
    New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action1 `
    -Principal $Principal1 `
    -Trigger $Trigger1 `
    -Settings $Settings1
  )
   Write-Host 'Created A New Task Named' -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black 
   Write-Host " - $TaskName1" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
}

###########################
### Create Ryzen Master ###
###########################
# Set folder\taskname or just taskname by itself
$TaskName2 = 'Start-Scripts\start_ryzen_master'
# File paths
$Action2 = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
-Execute 'C:\Program Files\AMD\RyzenMaster\bin\AMD Ryzen Master.exe' `
# User info
$Principal2 = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal `
-UserId 'JDESKTOP\jholl'`
-LogonType Interactive `
-RunLevel Highest
# When to run task
$Trigger2 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger `
-AtLogOn
# Task settings
$TimeSpan2 = New-TimeSpan `
-Minutes 3
$Settings2 = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet `
 -StartWhenAvailable `
 -AllowStartIfOnBatteries `
 -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries `
 -Priority 0 `
 -RestartCount 3 `
 -RestartInterval $TimeSpan2 `
 -ExecutionTimeLimit '00:00:00'

# If task already exists function
if((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'start_ryzen_master' -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue')){
   Write-Host "$TaskName2" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
   Write-Host " - Already Exists" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
}
else{
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$TaskName2" -InputObject (
    New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action2 `
    -Principal $Principal2 `
    -Trigger $Trigger2 `
    -Settings $Settings2
  )
   Write-Host 'Created A New Task Named' -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
   Write-Host " - $TaskName2" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
}

##########################
### Create CorsairLink ###
##########################
# Set folder\taskname or just taskname by itself
$TaskName3 = 'Start-Scripts\start_corsair_link'
# File paths
$Action3 = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
-Execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CorsairLink4\CorsairLink4.exe' `
# User info
$Principal3 = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal `
-UserId 'JDESKTOP\jholl' `
-LogonType Interactive `
-RunLevel Highest
# When to run task
$Trigger3 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger `
-AtLogOn
# Task settings
$TimeSpan3 = New-TimeSpan `
-Minutes 3
$Settings3 = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet `
 -StartWhenAvailable `
 -AllowStartIfOnBatteries `
 -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries `
 -Priority 0 `
 -RestartCount 3 `
 -RestartInterval $TimeSpan3 `
 -ExecutionTimeLimit '00:00:00'

# If task already exists function
if((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'start_corsair_link' -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue')){
   Write-Host "$TaskName3" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
   Write-Host " - Already Exists" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black

}
else{
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$TaskName3" -InputObject (
    New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action3 `
    -Principal $Principal3 `
    -Trigger $Trigger3 `
    -Settings $Settings3
  )
   Write-Host 'Created A New Task Named' -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
   Write-Host " - $TaskName3" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Script B:

```
##############################
######## CREATE TASKS ########
##############################
#
## ERROR STDOUT PREFERENCE ###
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
#
###### TIME-SPAN VALUE #######
$TimeSpan = New-TimeSpan `
-Minutes 3
#
##### WHEN TO RUN TASK #######
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger `
-AtLogOn
#
###### TASK OWNER INFO #######
$Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal `
-UserId "$Env:USERDOMAIN\$Env:USERNAME" `
-LogonType Interactive `
-RunLevel Highest
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet `
 -StartWhenAvailable `
 -AllowStartIfOnBatteries `
 -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries `
 -Priority 0 `
 -RestartCount 3 `
 -RestartInterval $TimeSpan `
 -ExecutionTimeLimit '00:00:00'
#
###### TASKS FOLDER NAME #####
$Folder = 'Start-Scripts'
#
######### TASKNAMES ##########
$TaskName1 = 'start_ahk_multiple_hotkeys'
$TaskName2 = 'start_ryzen_master'
$TaskName3 = 'start_corsair_link'
#
###### FOLDER + TASKNAME #####
$FullTask1 = "$Folder\$TaskName1"
$FullTask2 = "$Folder\$TaskName2"
$FullTask3 = "$Folder\$TaskName3"
#
############ AHK #############
$Action1 = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
-Execute "$Env:ProgramFiles\AHK\AutoHotkey.exe" `
-Argument "$Env:OneDrive\Documents\01_Scripts\02_AHK\Multiple_Hotkeys\Hotkeys_1.ahk"
#
########### RYZEN ############
$Action2 = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
-Execute "$Env:ProgramFiles\AMD\RyzenMaster\bin\AMD Ryzen Master.exe"
#
##############################
######## CORSAIRLINK #########
##############################
$Action3 = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
-Execute "$Env:ProgramFiles(x86)\CorsairLink4\CorsairLink4.exe"
#
#########  IF EXISTS #########
if((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$FullTask1" -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue')){
   Write-Host "$FullTask1" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
   Write-Host " - Already Exists" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
}
else{
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$FullTask1" -InputObject (
    New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action1 `
    -Principal $Principal `
    -Trigger $Trigger `
    -Settings $Settings
  )
   Write-Host 'A task was created -' -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
   Write-Host " - $FullTask1" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
}
#
########  IF EXISTS 2 ########
if((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$FullTask2" -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue')){
   Write-Host "$FullTask2" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
   Write-Host " - Already Exists" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
}
else{
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$FullTask2" -InputObject (
    New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action2 `
    -Principal $Principal `
    -Trigger $Trigger `
    -Settings $Settings
  )
   Write-Host 'A task was created -' -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
   Write-Host " - $FullTask2" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
}
#
########  IF EXISTS 3 ########
if((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$FullTask3" -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue')){
   Write-Host "$FullTask3" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
   Write-Host " - Already Exists" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
}
else{
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' -TaskName "$FullTask3" -InputObject (
    New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action3 `
    -Principal $Principal `
    -Trigger $Trigger `
    -Settings $Settings
  )
   Write-Host 'A task was created -' -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
   Write-Host " - $FullTask3" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
}
#
###### EXIT PARAMETERS #######
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: [1] your use of backticks is both unneeded AND a possible source of errors. i would remove them and use splatting where needed. [2] your 2nd script does not use the same code - it uses `$FullTast1` instead. are you certain that the resulting value is correct?

Comment: I had no idea the backticks were a worst practice move. Thanks for the info. Also to answer your question about the correct value I would say yes based on the fact that the tasks get created correctly and work. There is one thing however now that I remember that doesn't seems to work. When I restart my pc and log in the AutoHotKey Script shows two identical instances running instead of the correct 1 instance. Any idea what that is about?

Comment: backticks are too easy to forget, too easy to manage to leave a space _after a backtick, and just too dang difficult to SEE. [*grin*] ///// as for where the two AHK instances are coming from ... i would use something like process explorer or AutoRuns.exe to see what triggered each instance.

Comment: So per my update1 post above, I now seem to be triggering both else statments at once. What is going on?

Comment: you have THREE `if/else` blocks - which are showing errors? also, what is the error?

Comment: Each block is trigger both if/else statements at once. All three. I have no clue what is going on.

Comment: what does `
Each block is trigger both if/else statements at once` mean? do you mean that all three blocks trigger both the `if TRUE` and the `if FALSE` branches?

Comment: The yes and no statements in all three if blocks are simulataneously being called. So the if block is calling BOTH yes and no simultaneously.

Comment: that means you have a really bad logic error in your code somewhere. load the script into VSCode or the ISE and use the debugger to trace your path thru your code until you find the glitch. --- at this time, i don't see any such glitch in your `Update2:` code.